# What's a good way to add some property to nested auto-generated types/interfaces

Tags: typescript, web-applications, typing

I wrote some SPA web application. In it, fetch nested data from a web API.
The interfaces are following:

```js
interface A {
  id: string
  arrayOfB: B[]
}

interface B {
  id: string
  arrayOfC: C[]
}

interface C {
  id: string
  name: string
}
```

The response is JSON and it's schema is exactly interface A. These interfaces were automatically generated from the API definition.
Unfortunately, some libraries require a property "label" to build UI parts. So I had to append label property to C. But the interface definitions were auto-generated, so I don't want to change the definition of C, which stores a part of the API response.

The library requires following type:

```js
interface CForUI {
  id: string
  name: string  // not required
  label: string  // required
}
```

[image of interfaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvzBG.png)

I had some ideas:

1. create interfaces AForUI, BForUI

create

```js
interface AForUI {
  id: string
  arrayOfB: BForUI[]
}
```

and BForUI, CForUI. That's redundant and may increase impedance mismatch.

2. add property `label?: string` to interface C, and mutate C.

That's not redundant, but modifies auto-generated definitions. And if you only considered type, the label property may be null, so null check was forced. (Even if we don't mutated the data except when getting the response.)

```js
response.arrayOfB.forEach((b) => {
  b.arrayOfC.forEach((c) => {
    c.label = c.name
  })
})
```

3. add property `arrayOfCForUI: CForUI` to interface B, and mutate C.

```js
response.arrayOfB.forEach((b) => {
  b.arrayOfC.forEach((c) => {
    (c as CForUI).label = c.name
  })
  b.arrayOfCForUI = b.arrayOfC as CForUI[]
})
```

None of them look good. Are there any good solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `extends`? You create your own new interface and just extend the auto-generated interface.

```
interface ExtendedC extends C {
  label: string;
}
```

This will use auto-generated C properties and append your `label` property to it.

Comment: Thanks!
It reduces rewrite auto-generated C properties, but still have to write code similar to 1 or 3. One idea is to auto-generate ExtendedA, ExtendedB and ExtendedC as empty extended interfaces with empty methods to modify it. (similar to 1)